# How to send commands to Powershell from Python as an administrator?

Tags: python, powershell

How send slmgr /ipk W269N-WFGWX-YVC9B-4J6C9-T83GX as an administrator to Powershell

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['powershell', 'slmgr /ipk W269N-WFGWX-YVC9B-4J6C9-T83GX'])
proc.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't really test this with your command but this works for example to start the cmd from powershell as an admin:

```py
import ctypes


def run_as_admin(command):
    result = ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(
        None, "runas", "powershell", command, None, 1)
    if result <= 32:
        raise Exception("Failed to run as admin")


run_as_admin("start cmd")

# your command would need to be like this instead:
# run_as_admin("slmgr /ipk W269N-WFGWX-YVC9B-4J6C9-T83GX")
```